# Styling dropdown a11y and without js?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, dropdown

Is there a way to style a HTML Dropdown Menu that is accessible and has no JS?

At the moment I see only Solutions with JS, jQuery or `webkit-appearance: none;`
But I don't like it at all because I don't think those solutions would be accessible.

Comment: Could you reword your question a bit as the solution accepted uses jQuery and Bootstrap JS so I must have misunderstood what you meant by no JavaScript and others might also. I guess you meant no inline styles? This way anyone who stumbles across your question in the future doesn't end up misunderstanding as I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please check the following url for reference

> Blockquote

https://codepen.io/srirachachacha/pen/VPKjjx
```

Comment: I have to agree with @GrahamRitchie. It's odd to accept an answer that uses bootstrap and jQuery when the question stipulated no JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit for clarity

As pointed out in the comments this advice applies to a "fly-out" menu, or a drop-down menu that is part of navigation.

If you are creating a web application with a toolbar style menu (a menu that contains buttons that trigger functions etc. instead of navigation) then the guidance and behaviour is very different.

With that being said, the general answer is still the same **you cannot create a drop-down that is accessible without some JavaScript**

### Original Answer

JavaScript has nothing to do with styling, judging by the rest of your question I have assumed you meant create a drop-down menu not how to style it.

You cannot make an accessible drop down menu without JavaScript. There are a few reasons for this:-

1. You need to be able to toggle `aria-expanded` on the button that opens the drop down.
2. The drop down list should only appear on pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>space</kbd> (with <kbd>enter</kbd> being the normal way of doing it).
3. You need to manage focus states so that when someone tabs on the last item in a drop-down menu it goes to the next top-level menu item and closes the drop-down menu automatically.
4. You should be able to navigate the drop-down menu with arrow keys ideally (not essential but a nice to have).
5. Pressing `Esc` should ideally close the menu, not essential for compliance but a lot better experience for keyboard users.

There are other reasons but this should give you an idea of why JavaScript is needed.

With that being said if you are worried about people who do not have JavaScript enabled you can provide a fall-back link to a HTML sitemap. You can do this using a `<noscript>` tag.

Also bear in mind JavaScript in itself is not an accessibility issue, the accessibility issues caused by JavaScript are down to developers and as long as you provide a fall-back it is actually an essential tool in accessibility best practices.

Comment: An informative answer.

In reason number 3, to be clear, per [WAI guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/#menu), tabbing should not navigate to and from menu items but to and from the widget as a whole.

In reason number 4, to be clear, arrow key navigation is required, not optional, per guidelines.

Comment: My whole answer needs a rewrite, it is misleading if you think I am talking about an application menu (which is my fault), but if this was a navigation flyout menu (which is what the advice was for) navigation by `Tab` is highly recommended see https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/flyout/#use-parent-as-toggle and it complies with the recommended pattern. The advice in the WAI-ARIA guidelines you linked is for toolbar style menus for web applications not normal website navigation. I will try and rewrite / expand the answer later in the week. Thanks for letting me know this answer was sub-par!

Comment: @cagerattler I have now updated the answer to include clarity of what I am describing to avoid further confusion, let me know if that makes sense now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify, @GrahamRitchie. The two patterns we are siting differ greatly. In other alternate patterns, table versus grid for example, WAI is clear that the more typical arrow key navigation used in other compound widgets is required whenever the options are numerous or there is a persistent method of selection. In the absence of qualifying guidelines, I tend would view the "fly out" pattern in the same light. I did reach out to the authors for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<nav role="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
li {
 display: block;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```