# Is using the Details Element as a "dropdown menu" A11Y-friendly?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, sveltekit

I've been looking for a way to add an accessible "Dropdown Menu", more specifically, a navigation "menu" (i.e. `<nav></nav>`) that opens via clicking on it or pressing `Enter` but remains keyboard and screen-reader accessible **using SvelteKit**.

Most of the examples I found were either similar to [this one](https://codepen.io/grayghostvisuals/pen/AqYyNX), which uses `hover` state to open them when the user is using a mouse; they depend too much on either a mouse click or screen tap using JavaScript and are not very accessible via keyboard; or were part of a UI library.

The solution I came up with is to use the `details` element, like so:

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
  let isMenuLinkFocused = false;

  // Get the currently selected link and detect whether the user is going forwards or backwards
  // in the list of links in order to decide when to close the <details> element.
  function current(event, id) {
    if (event.which === 9) {
      if(event.shiftKey === true) {
        console.log("BACKWARD - ID: " + id);
        if (id === 0) {
          isMenuLinkFocused = false;
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log("FORWARD - ID: " + id);

        if (id === 3) {
          isMenuLinkFocused = false;
        }
      }
    }
    if (event.which === 27) {
      isMenuLinkFocused = false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
  <details bind:open={isMenuLinkFocused}>
    <summary>Main menu</summary>
    <ul>
      <li><a on:keydown={(e) => {current(e, 0)}} href="#a">Home</a></li>
      <li><a on:keydown={(e) => {current(e, 1)}} href="#b">Products</a></li>
      <li><a on:keydown={(e) => {current(e, 2)}} href="#c">Services</a></li>
      <li><a on:keydown={(e) => {current(e, 3)}} href="#d">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </details>
</nav>
```

As per the recommendations in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60486699/styling-dropdown-a11y-and-without-js):

1. It covers the `aria-expanded` part because `<details>` has an [Implicit ARIA role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) of `group`.
2. By default it opens via `Enter` and `Space` keys.
3. Thanks to the `current()` function, it closes after you go forwards past the last link and after you go backwards past the first link.
4. `Tab` is used for navigation as per his clarified comment in his post.
5. Thanks to the `current()` function it closes when `Esc` key (`event.which === 27`) is pressed.

**QUESTION:**

Would this be A11Y-friendly? Have I missed something?

Comment: Thanks to the current() function, it closes after you go forwards past the last link and after you go backwards past the first link. => This is in fact a bad idea. Partially sighted and blind user may not understand why it opens and closes unexpectedly. This is a pure visual thing that should be avoided.

Comment: @QuentinC So, point **#3** from the post is only recommended when you have multiple menus and not a single one, like in my case? Would closing it when `Enter` is pressed when one of the links is currently selected a good alternative? Basically, add the check `if (event.which === 13) { isMenuLinkFocused = false; }` - this is for when a link leads to a section on the current route.

Comment: Yes. The fact that a menu disappears after an option is selected is a behavior that can reasonably be expected and that will be understood. Depending on what it does it may be annoying, but it isn't surprising at all. Except that I would count on click event rather than specifically intercepting enter key. You should behave the same regardless of if the user activated the link by clicking with the mouse, taping (or double taping) the screen, or pressing enter.